# Access Violation exception after migration from vs 2010 to vs 2013 toolset

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2013, upgrade, access-violation

I have an old C++ MFC Application

when I upgraded the solution to use the visual studio 2013 toolset instead of visual studio 2010 and then recompiled it successfully, at the runtime and access violation exception occurred and when i recompiled again with 2010 tool set the exception has gone, I debugged it and found that when a class [that override a parent virtual method and call it's parents method from that override method] when the debugger hit a breakpoint in that overridden method  the member values was correct when it called its parent's method and begfore executing a single statement the member values are random for example Parent=>0x06d6ef it became 0xfffff and the hWnd for a CWnd was 0x00000 and became 0x000001 and so on when if checked if member Parent != nullptr then called a method in it, and that caused the exception. the this pointer stayed correct with its value when was executing in child

the question here is why the members data was corrupted and it's values was changed, this don't happen when i compile with toolset vs 2010.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding?

Comment: I cleaned it and built it many times, I rebuilt the whole solution but it still firing the exception, I mapped the solution to a clean pc and rebuilt the solution, and I got the same results

Comment: longest phrase ever :/ i am experiencing similar problems, but can you rephrase, reformat and provide examples?

Comment: @x29a : sorry for my messy words, I'm not a native english speaker and that moment I was so confused because of that problem, and still facing it till now.

Comment: do you face the problems in both configurations, debug and release?